# adding a key to the registry

Tags: registry, handler

I am trying to follow instructions in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx#app_reg

but I am not very familiar with regedit. What I do not understand, is how to add the following to the registry:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"

Can I do this in regedit? Is there a file to which I can just add these lines?
Thanks a lot in advance!

All the best,

Giuseppe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open RegEdit (elevated)
2. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT then select New > Key
3. Type 'alert'
4. Right click on 'alert' then select New > String value
5. Type (Default), then double click on the entry and write your value ie. "URL:Alert Protocol"
6. Repeat for the other entries, respecting the hierarchy and entry type of your list (NB. in the link you provided - DefaultIcon, shell, open and command are all Keys and the (Default) entries are all String Value)

Once you have all your entries, you can always right-click on any of the keys (the folders) and "Export" to file. Importing the resulting file is easy - just click on it :)

Hope this helps.

Leo

Comment: What do you mean? How? When?

Comment: managed, no worries! thanks again! I was wondering if it is possible to execute a batch file. It worked.